# Partition backup software

Tags: partition, backup-restoration

I've used Ghost in the past and creating and recovering partitions was easy. Then I tried Acronis and it's a mess. Too many options, menus mixed-up. The problem is that the partition that I want to back-up is around 15 GB, larger that the DVD size limit. Should I switch back to Ghost? Try something else?

Comment: It sounds like you should switch to a USB hard-drive for storing your images.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using usb hdd, guess I will have to spit my image between mutiple DVDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the OS, I have found Symantec Backup Exec System Recovery good for backing up partitions or entire systems.  Interface user friendly and seems to compress well.  60 day trial is on their site.  Still like and use GHOST as well but BESR adds some nice features including restore a system to different hardware.